# Share option in Flutter Webview using react-web-share

Tags: reactjs, flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview, react-share

I have a app in flutter and using InAppWebView for opening a URL which is developed in React TypeScript.

On that URL page I have Share button.

So I want to share the data using installed apps from the mobile.

I tried using react-web-share Library. But if I click on the button from InAppWebview of the app it showing like below image :
[image]

And If I open the same URL from browser the it is working fine and showing options with installed app. As shown in below image

[image]

I want the same result from InAppWebView

Comment: Can you share the url you want to go?

Comment: I am opening url : www.nuuu.com/mf